# ¿Como puedo corregir el error al tratar con listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Tengo el siguiente código ya hecho**

```
def text_with_pattern(arg, file_url):
    file = open(file_url, "r")
    d = [linea.rstrip('\n').split(':') for linea in file]
    file.close()
    print(d)

    for element in d:

        frase = arg.replace('0', element[0])

        print(frase)

text_with_pattern("1 say to 0 that 2 doens`t work today", "filename.txt")
```

**Como resultado obtengo lo siguiente:**

*Console*

```
[['Miguel', 'Juan', 'Pedro'], ['Luis', 'Antonio', 'Maria'], ['Marcos', 'Eva'], ['Ivan', 'Jesus', 'Antonio', 'Luis'], ['Rafael', 'Francisco', 'Jose']]
1 say to Miguel that 2 doens`t work today
1 say to Luis that 2 doens`t work today
1 say to Marcos that 2 doens`t work today
1 say to Ivan that 2 doens`t work today
1 say to Rafael that 2 doens`t work today
```

**Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente**

Pasándole un texto tipo **string**, como por ejemplo:"*1 say to 0 that 2 doesn't work today*"

**Hay que tener en cuenta que en el **string** pasado pueden existir dígitos numéricos de 0 al 9, y en caso de no tener suficientes elementos en el array no simplemente no se reemplazaran**
reemplazar esos numero por los elementos que tenemos guardados en los array dentro del array 2D,
es decir:

```
Juan say to Miguel that Pedro doens`t work today
```

para el primer array y así sucesivamente.

**He conseguido lo mostrado en el resultado pero no doy con la tecla para solucionarlo**

*Gracias*

Comment: Hay items como `['Marcos', 'Eva']` que no contienen tres elementos; ¿qué hacer en tales casos?

Comment: @CandidMoe Pues poner solo los que haya

Answer (score 1):

Podemos reducir el problema planteado a su parte esencial, que es el reemplazo de los enteros por el correspondiente elemento en la lista:

```
def text_with_pattern(arg, lista):
    frase = arg
    for idx in range(len(lista)):
        frase = frase.replace(str(idx), lista[idx])

    return frase
```

Es básicamente lo mismo que has escrito, pero generalizando para cualquier entero.

Los argumentos son:

- `arg`, el patrón de reemplazo.
- `lista`, una simple lista con nombres.

Con `str(idx)` transformamos los enteros `0, 1, 2, ...` a su representación como caracteres `'0', '1', '2', ...`. La función `replace` entonces cambia ese entero por su correspondiente elemento en la lista, dado por `lista[idx]`.

Bueno, de ahí puedes agregar el proceso de lectura desde el archivo, que ya lo tienes hecho.

**Demo**

```
tests = [['Miguel', 'Juan', 'Pedro'],
         ['Luis', 'Antonio', 'Maria'],
         ['Marcos', 'Eva'],
         ['Ivan', 'Jesus', 'Antonio', 'Luis'],
         ['Rafael', 'Francisco', 'Jose']]

expresion = "1 say to 0 that 2 doesn't work today"
for test in tests:
    print(text_with_pattern(expresion, test))
```

produce:

```
Juan say to Miguel that Pedro doesn't work today
Antonio say to Luis that Maria doesn't work today
Eva say to Marcos that 2 doesn't work today
Jesus say to Ivan that Antonio doesn't work today
Francisco say to Rafael that Jose doesn't work today
```

Comment: Lo intento implementar y te cuento, muchas gracias @Candid Moe

Comment: en ```for idx in range(len(test)):``` ```test ```a que hace referencia?

Comment: @AntonioOrtegaChinchilla. Error de tipeo; es `lista`. Corregi la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias.